# meta_query between two date in wordpress not working

Tags: wordpress

I tried **meta_query** but not working.

Need post data between particular date 2016-01-01 to 2017-01-01 but not working my code is :

```
$args = array( 
     'post_type' => 'post',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'category' => array( 7, 11, 463, 409 ),
    'post_status' => array('publish'),  
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
     'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'post_date',
            'value' => array("2016-01-01", "2017-01-01"),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        )
    )
    );
```

Comment: Why `DATETIME` for values that seem to be date only?

Comment: @CBroe yes but date is also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution please check below code :

```
    $args = array( 
         'post_type' => 'post',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'category' => array( 7, 11, 463, 409 ),
        'post_status' => array('publish'),  
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'column' => 'post_modified',
                'after'     => $last_fetch_date,
                'before'    => $current_time,
                'inclusive' => true,
            ),
        ),
   );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your meta contains only date format, Test the below code also dump the query using var_dump or echo the query which runs depends on your `args` Run the query in database to verify the data is setted in that format same as you want to get it by query. comment out the category line to make sure your post is returning or not, IF Return then check post the category is selected in the posts

```
$start = '2016-01-01';
$end   = '2017-01-01';
$args  = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'title',
    'category'       => array(7, 11, 463, 409),
    'meta_key'   => 'post_date',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'post_date',
            'value'   => array($start, $end),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type'    => 'DATE'
        )
    )
);
// Make the query
$Query = new WP_Query();
echo 'SQL: '.$Query->request.'<br>'; // your query against args
```

Comment: Have you try dumping the query ? and re-check the post data ? edit your question with the data and query output.